# Trigger event when an element exists

Tags: jquery

I have an empty `div` element:

```
<div class="message"></div>
```

At certain point of the webpage, a `p` tag is dynamically added to the div:

```
<div class="message">
  <p>Some Message</p>
</div>
```

The `p` can get removed, then added again and so.

What event should I use to listen if the `div.message` has a `p` child and execute some code?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219795/jquery-element-exists-event) question, but it involves external plugins.

Isn't there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: How is this element added and removed?

Comment: Via jquery.validation plugin. I could insert the code from there but I'm looking for another solution keeping that code untouched

Comment: I would be surprised if the plugin doesn't have some configurable callbacks that run before that element is created. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762458/customising-event-delegates-in-the-jquery-validation-plug-in. `highlight` looks promising.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on your implementation and how fast you need to recognize a change, you might be able to get away with using a `setInterval` to periodically monitor the contents of a certain element.

```
var checkContents = setInterval(function(){
  if ($("div.message p").length > 0){ // Check if element has been found
    // There is a <p> element in here!!
    console.log($("div.message p").length());
  }
},1000);
```

The previous snippet will check for `<p>` elements within `div.message` elements every second (1000 milliseconds), and if present will log the number of them to the console.

---

Depending on your browser support requirements, you could alternatively use mutation events -

> [Mutation events provide a mechanism for a web page or an extension to
>   get notified about changes made to the DOM...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events)

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('div.message')
element.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
  // ...
}, false);
```

Comment: Mutation events are now superceded by Mutation Observers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent it is deprecated.

Comment: Quite surprised this is the top answer, Can someone comment on the effects on the page of constantly (once per second) checking if this element exists? I don't really like "polling" like this but it's a quick easy fix until I can implement something better which I feel would perform better such. as the mutation observer.

Comment: @SwimmingG - not 100% how relevant this answer is 9yrs later. Having a 1 second poll shouldn't have a massive effect on the page but this depends what else is happening on the page. I wouldn't recommend using this same method to detect multiple changes - creating too many simultaneous setIntervals probably will have a negative effect on any other JS that is being run at the same time. 
[Mutation observers](https://caniuse.com/mutationobserver) might be a better choice depending on your browser support.

Comment: @Lix thanks I'll check them out :)

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS has an awesome way to detect any DOM changes (including if a node adds any child nodes), check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

But these docs aren't super clear so here's a quick explanation.

First, you want to have a target node to listen to:

```
const targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');
```

Then you want to create a trigger when the target changes (called MutationObserver):

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(callbackFunction);
```

Define what you want to happen when the target changes:

```
const callbackFunction = function(mutationsList) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};
```

note: mutationsList is an object with loads of information what the targetNode has changed including style, addedNodes, etc...

Finally, you can start observing the target node for mutations (changes) with:

```
observer.observe(targetNode, {
    childlist: true,
    attributes: true
});
```

The second parameter is an 'options' object to define what type of mutation (changes) you're looking for.

Hopefully that helps, I've found it to be a really powerful and underrated tool in js

Comment: This is great.  Using MutationObserver with this --> `document.contains(myElement)` within the `MutationObserver` was the best route for my build.  See also this link.  Also no JQuery. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420577/detect-added-element-to-dom-with-mutation-observer