# Detect added element to DOM with Mutation Observer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mutation-events

I'm adding some element to DOM after drag event. I need to detect this element and the moment when this element was added. I use Mutation Observer but something is wrong, the code:

```
var targetNodes = $('.mvly');
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
var myObserver = new MutationObserver (mutationHandler);
var obsConfig = { childList: true, characterData: true, attributes: true, subtree: true };

targetNodes.each(function(){
    myObserver.observe(this, obsConfig);
} );

function mutationHandler (mutationRecords) {
    mutationRecords.forEach ( function (mutation) {
        if (typeof mutation.addedNodes == "object") {
            console.log('test');
        }
    });
}
```

Can anybody help, much thx.

Comment: Your code works for me, which browser do you use?

Comment: I haven't any response from console... :(

Comment: Are you actually mutating the DOM after you set the handler? What you have done handles mutations concerning the .mvly elements. If you want to catch the .mvly elements being added, you need to observe their parents (before they are added).

Comment: so i need to set `myObserver.observe(this.parentNode, obsConfig);`?

Answer (score 30):

Here's a simple example of how you can use a `MutationObserver` to listen for when an element is added to the DOM.

For brevity, I'm using jQuery syntax to build the node and insert it into the DOM.

```
var myElement = $("<div>hello world</div>")[0];

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
   if (document.contains(myElement)) {
        console.log("It's in the DOM!");
        observer.disconnect();
    }
});

observer.observe(document, {attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree:true});

$("body").append(myElement); // console.log: It's in the DOM!
```

You don't need to iterate over each MutationRecord stored in `mutations` because you can perform the `document.contains` check directly upon `myElement`.

Comment: Saved the day.  Using this I was able to remove all of my original code that was applying click events to any element that could detect the child nodes.  My code is now easier to read and so many less lines.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why it's not present in the mutation records (`mutations` in the answer's example)?

Comment: Now I know why, b/c it case of the node addition/removal the `.target` of the mutation record will be the parent (in the case of this answer — the document itself)