# Get the newly created elements and assign onClick function or add click event

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I've been trying to use MutationObserver. I can get it to report if any element has been added to the DOM, but I can't reference these elements. I need to apply certain functions to them.

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<div id="main">
Some Links
 <a href="www.123.com" class="myLink">Link 1</a>
 <a href="www.456.com" class="myLink">Link 2</a>
 <a href="www.789.com" class="myLink">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

New links may be added to this DIV element when I scroll. What I need is to **get these new link elements and reference them** in Javascript.

Note that it's not the exact tree. It's possibly much more nested, not so basic. But the **myLink** classes are there.

Performance is a slight worry, compatibility is not.

Comment: a  good example of observer in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420577/detect-added-element-to-dom-with-mutation-observer

Comment: @Liquidchrome That doesn't help me to get the new elements as variables or in an array, in any format that I can reference them with. I can already get it to report if any element has been added to the DOM.